# Validacion de campo numerico que esten vacios

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo un problema el cual quiero colocar como regla de negocio el set de codigo que no quede vacio se hacerlo con tipo string pero int no si alguien me puede ayudar porfavor gracias!

```
public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}
```

Comment: un int ya de por si no pude ser vacio, a que te refieres con vacio?

Comment: que me pide por regla de negocio que cuando se ingrese valor a codigo no este vacio

Comment: pero el codigo es alfanumerico? o solo numerico?

Comment: osea solo quiero colocar que no quede espacios vacios en cantidad se que es un isempty para string o ==null pero en int no puedo

Comment: es int no puede tener null, no es una referencia como string, siempre en un int tendras un valor

Comment: si pero estoy haciendo un scanner amigazo como puedo realizar que el la cantidad no quede vacio cuando el usuario ingresa ?

Comment: para ello puedes hacer que el valor que lee el scanner sea un numero con un int.parse(string) esto lanzara una excepcion si la cadena no es un numero

Comment: ah entiendo muchas gracias! se pso